# Why native epoll support is introduced in Netty?

Tags: netty, nio, epoll

I believe Java's NIO library will use epoll on Linux machines. What are all the advantages of using Epoll instead of NIO on Linux machines.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Netty's epoll transport uses epoll edge-triggered while java's nio library uses level-triggered. Beside this the epoll transport expose configuration options that are not present with java's nio like TCP_CORK, SO_REUSEPORT and more.

Comment: Any reference for "java's nio library uses level-triggered"?

Comment: Just look at how its is implemented in the JDK. Also otherwise it would not work with the `Selector` interface.

Answer (score 3):

There are some information about this in [netty's docs](https://netty.io/wiki/native-transports.html):

> Netty provides the following platform specific JNI transports:
>
> ```
> Linux (since 4.0.16)
> MacOS/BSD (since 4.1.11)
> ```
>
> These JNI transports add features specific to a particular platform, generate less garbage, and generally improve performance when compared to the NIO based transport.