# Java NIO why Selector has to work with Channel in non-blocking mode?

Tags: java, nio, epoll

According to [this passage](https://eklitzke.org/blocking-io-nonblocking-io-and-epoll), IO Multiplexing can work with file descriptors in both blocking and non-blocking mode:
[image]

And non-blocking mode is only needed to cooperate with edge-triggered mode:
[image]

What's more, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23465481/9107303), Java NIO works in lever-triggered mode.

Then why Java NIO Selector requires the channel to be in the non-blocking mode:
[image]

Thanks to your reply in advance.

Comment: Using selectors in blocking mode is quite problematic. Possibly the Java NIO designers opted to avoid the whole issue.

Answer (score -1):

The power of `java.nio` and the `Channel` comes from the fact that you can watch over multiple sockets in a non-blocking way. In other words, the traditional `java.io` was a `single-thread / single-socket` approach with blocking IO calls, whereas `java.nio` is meant for a usage where you can spawn thousands of socket connection (via channels and selector) without requiring thousands of threads. Here the job of the selector is to help your thread / thread pool read & write from the channels which are ready and connected.

Java Docs for Channel defines it as,

> Defines channels, which represent connections to entities that are
> capable of performing I/O operations, such as files and sockets;
> defines selectors, for multiplexed, non-blocking I/O operations

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.