# How does Reactor Netty client internally decide which Channel object to use

Tags: java, spring-webflux, netty, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I have created an object of `HttpClient` class(from Reactor Netty jar), and used this httpClient to create an object of `Webclient` class(from Spring Webflux jar) as below:

```
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
        .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 5000)
        .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
        .option(EpollChannelOption.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 300)
        .option(EpollChannelOption.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 60)
        .option(EpollChannelOption.TCP_KEEPCNT, 8)
        .doOnConnected(//custom stuff);



    Webclient webclient = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl()
        .defaultHeader()
        .codecs(
                configurer -> {
                    configurer.defaultCodecs().jaxb2Encoder(new Jaxb2XmlEncoder());
                    configurer.defaultCodecs().jaxb2Decoder(new Jaxb2XmlDecoder());
                })
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)
        .build();
```

Then I'm using this WebClient to make a POST API request.

Although I'm getting the API response correctly, I was getting below warnings in the logs:

```
Unknown channel option 'io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollChannelOption#TCP_KEEPIDLE' for channel '[id: 0x76c8c652]'

Unknown channel option 'io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollChannelOption#TCP_KEEPCNT' for channel '[id: 0x76c8c652]'

Unknown channel option 'io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollChannelOption#TCP_KEEPINTVL' for channel '[id: 0x76c8c652]'
```

The properties(`TCP_KEEPIDLE, TCP_KEEPCNT`, `TCP_KEEPINTVL` etc) in the above warning are  set in the HttpClient` object creation code as shown in the above code.

I debugged this and found out that the warnings are getting generated in
`TransportConnector.setChannelOptions(Channel channel, Map<ChannelOption<?>, ?> options, boolean isDomainSocket)` method which is there in the reactor netty jar.

And the reason the warnings are coming is because the `Channel` object in the above mentioned method is an object of `NioSocketChannel`. After reading the `reactor netty` documentation I realized that if the Channel is `NioSocketChannel` then we need to change the configs from `EpollChannelOption` to `NioChannelOption` as below:

```
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
        .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 5000)
        .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
        .option(NioChannelOption.of(ExtendedSocketOptions.TCP_KEEPIDLE), 300)
        .option(NioChannelOption.of(ExtendedSocketOptions.TCP_KEEPINTERVAL), 60)
        .option(NioChannelOption.of(ExtendedSocketOptions.TCP_KEEPCOUNT), 8)
        .doOnConnected(//custom stuff);
```

And it worked fine after the above change, as no warnings are coming now.

However here is my **problem** needing clarification:

This exact project has been working fine in one of our production environment. Also from the logs I could see the underlying `channel` in production was `EpollSocketChannelConfig` in contrast to my local where the `channel` was `NioSocketChannel`.

In what circumstances can the  underlying `Channel` be different for the same codebase?

I haven't used the `runOn`  method either anywhere in the codebase.

Some info about my setup:
My local is a Mac M1 is where the Channel is NIO
whereas
the Production is running Linux where the Channel is NIO.

The java version in both the machines is Java 11.

Please help

Comment: You need the [epoll dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-transport-native-epoll) to use epoll - which includes native code. You also need to be running a UNIX OS (ie not windows). Otherwise NIO is a generic platform agnostic solution.

Comment: even with docker, it still seems to use NIO. not epoll. It is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Netty provides platform-specific JNI transports. I see `netty-transport-native-epoll` dependency only for `linux-x86_64` architecture. That is most probably why you see such warnings for Mac `osx-aarch_64`.

See https://netty.io/wiki/native-transports.html and https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#connection-timeout